# Odd error !! HdInsight Hadoop MapReduce fails with code 255

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm using Microsoft Azure's HdInsight with 1 head node & 1 data node.

If I use a small dataset (85 MB) with the MapReduce programs I wrote, everything works fine and I get the desired output in my container/blob. Larger files fail with the errors below.

I read some articles that mention the setting mapreduce.map.memory.mb should be set to "1024" so the mapper has more memory. I dont understand how this can scale, considering that I have 190 GB files I want to process and none of the cluster's machines have anywhere near that amount of RAM.

**I'm sure there is something small I'm missing, but does anyone know how I should 1) resolve this issue 2) make it so I can scale the mapReduce processes up to large input files without these errors ?**

If I use an input file that is 8 GB then I get the error below:

```
15/08/01 05:43:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 56% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 57% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 58% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1438405138600_0006_m_0
010_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess
iled with code 255
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed
ava:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.ja
:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInfor
tion.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

15/08/01 05:43:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 57% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 58% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 59% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 61% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:43:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 62% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1438405138600_0006_m_0
010_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess
iled with code 255
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed
ava:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.ja
:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInfor
tion.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

15/08/01 05:44:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 61% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 62% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 64% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 65% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 66% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 69% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 70% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1438405138600_0006_m_0
010_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess
iled with code 255
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed
ava:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.ja
:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInfor
tion.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

15/08/01 05:44:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 68% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:44:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 71% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:45:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 72% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:45:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:45:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 76% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:45:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 77% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:45:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 78% reduce 0%
15/08/01 05:45:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/08/01 05:45:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1438405138600_0006 failed with s
te FAILED due to: Task failed task_1438405138600_0006_m_000010
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

15/08/01 05:45:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 35
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                FILE: Number of bytes written=605590393
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                WASB: Number of bytes read=5915160278
                WASB: Number of bytes written=0
                WASB: Number of read operations=0
                WASB: Number of large read operations=0
                WASB: Number of write operations=0
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Killed map tasks=3
                Launched map tasks=18
                Other local map tasks=3
                Rack-local map tasks=15
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1441061
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=1441061
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=1441061
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=1475646464
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=16375
                Map output records=319985
                Map output bytes=5051193751
                Map output materialized bytes=604451353
                Input split bytes=1210
                Combine input records=0
                Spilled Records=319985
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=2836
                CPU time spent (ms)=1003820
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=9417678848
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=13221376000
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=11603542016
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=5915148288
15/08/01 05:45:28 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

First: 1024 is 1GB of ram.  A1 is typically the standard size folks use when testing, which is 1.75 GB, you would then be using A0, which is 768mb.  This does not however read like a memory issue.  I would expect an error similiar to this:

*"Container[pid=container_1406552545451_0009_01_000002,containerID=container_234132_0001_01_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 569.1 MB of 512 MB physical memory used; 970.1 MB of 1.0 GB virtual memory used. Killing container."*

This error output reads to me like a job configuration issue.   Have you ensured that your build target is x64 and prefer 32 bit is unchecked?  See this thread on msdn: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d79befb1-be5d-4c5a-bb05-30ea9fccc475/hdinsight-mapreduce-fails-with-pipemapredwaitoutputthreads-subprocess-failed-with-code-255?forum=hdinsight